What are the main subjects covered in an aerospace engineering degree course?
Suppose someone wanted to self-study by reading some of the main textbooks that are covered in an undergraduate degree on aerospace engineering.
What are the main topics that are covered?
(As reference, I could say that the main topics I studied for computer software engineering were: Calculus, Physics, Engineering Mathematics, Electrical circuits, Digital Circuits, Discrete Mathematics, Graph Theory, Automata and Languages, Algorithm design and analysis, Java/Python/C++, Systems Design, Computer Languages, Computer Organization, Operating systems, Compiler design, Artificial Intelligence, Computer Graphics.  I want a similar list for aerospace engineering.)

For example: https://student.mit.edu/catalog/m16a.html

@sophit, That's useful, thank you

Another curriculum example from CU Boulder:  BS AES Curriculum with a link to the complete course catalog.

Every university will have its course catalog available online.  This will include the degree requirements for every major including short (one-paragraph) descriptions of every course offered.  You may also be able to find individual course websites (if the instructor makes one public) that includes a course outline, with a listed textbook, topics, and sometimes even homeworks and projects.
In the US, engineering schools are accredited through ABET (www.abet.org), which has criteria for engineering in general as well as subject specific requirements.  Their criteria are listed here.
There are three distinctions that are important -- aeronautical, astronautical, and aerospace.
The vast majority of programs in the US are 'Aerospace'.  This covers both aircraft and spacecraft applications.  Aeronautical restricts itself to aircraft applications and astronautical restricts itself to spacecraft applications.
The Aerospace standard is basically that it must contain everything from either aero or astro -- and 'some' from the other.  Consequently, most 'aerospace' programs are strongly tilted towards either aeronautical or astronautical.  (Most of them tilt aero).
If you are looking for a school to attend and you know for sure that you want to focus on air/space, then you should do some deeper research into the schools you are considering and figure out if their focus aligns with your interests.  If you are unsure, then try to find a school that provides a rich experience for either track.  This may seem counterintuitive, but you want as many courses split as possible.  Note, even though you can delay your decision a little, you will need to decide in the first year or two of university.  In the first two years, you are mostly taking foundation courses (Math, Science, etc. followed by basic Engineering - Statics, Thermo, Dynamics, etc.) and you don't get into your Major specific disciplinary courses until 3rd and 4th year.

Thanks for your response.  I did an undergraduate in Computer (Software) Engineering 20 years ago -- I'm trying to see if I can self-study aerospace engineering sufficiently to hop straight onto a graduate degree -- or possibly reduce the duration of a full new undergraduate degree somehow.  If you have any advice I would be grateful.

I would encourage you to look at software jobs at Aerospace companies.  Aircraft and spacecraft are basically flying computers these days and there are lots of interesting software challenges across the product lifecycle.  Anecdotally, aircraft companies struggle to recruit software people (because they all think the good jobs are in Silicon Valley) -- while their jobs for 'aerospace engineers' are very competitive.  Once you're at an Aerospace company and you see the various roles, reconsider more education -- they'll probably pay for it.

Thanks Rob but I've already made enough money to have no need for a job; I just wanted to learn more things in a setting surrounded by other people as self-study is limited.

In that case, it may be complicated.  These days, many universities don't have a straightforward mechanism for a person with a BS to apply to a BS program.  If you do, they don't know how to give credit for all the courses taken in the first BS program.  At the same time, some departments may have very strict requirements for what degrees they allow into their graduate program (these requirements may not be written anywhere and can vary wildly within an institution).

I would encourage you to reach out to your target department and talk with the Graduate Coordinator, Department Chair, or potential MS advisor.  I would explain your situation and come with a willingness to take background classes.
I would encourage you to take as much of the second half of the BS AE program as you can (the first half is likely redundant with the degree you have already).  You will learn a lot more by taking the classes in a normal manner - being forced to do projects / homeworks and getting to do the labs, etc.  This may well be the fun stuff you're most interested in.

After taking the background classes, you'll be able to proceed to a MS.  The courses will be more specialized, and you'll spend a lot of your time on your research project.  I would encourage you to find a university where a MS Thesis is the norm (vs. a non-thesis Special Project of some sort).  Unless you want to go all the way to Ph.D. -- in that case, don't worry about the MS Thesis and proceed...

Graduate education in the US is very expensive.  Even if you can afford it, you should pursue financial support.  That is the business of research universities and in general, if you aren't being paid to go there, you don't belong.

Thank you for your helpful comments; much appreciated.
